# igetting data in json form using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, json, jquery

Hi I was trying to get 2 dimensional array from php using ajax ,jquery ,but I am not able to get the response
here is my code

html code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_data.php",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                var data = json.msg;

                initChart(data);
            }
        });
```

php code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$responce=array();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
  $responce[]=array($i,$j);
}

echo json_encode(array("msg"=>$responce));
```

but I am getting message "json is empty " when debugged in Bugzilla

Comment: You have not initalized $j

Comment: Where is `$j` defined?

Comment: i have alredy initialised it in my php file

Comment: Don't use `POST` for getting data, by the way.

Comment: @moonwave99..changed it to GET but didnt worked:(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean?

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<10;$j++) {
        $responce[]=array($i,$j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$response = array();

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $response[$i] = array();
    for($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $response[$i][$j] = 10 * $i + $j;//Value is just an example. The important part is the left hand side of the assignment.
    }
}
```

Comment: Then there's a bug somewhere else in the code. Make sure nothing else is put into the output stream, neither before nor after `echo json_encode(...)`.